# Unable to search a text in jsonb object field

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a `jsondata` column which has a `jsonb` object (not array). This column includes many fields but every row has a `message` field. I want to do `~*` (or FTS if possible) on this field.

```sql
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id                bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    (MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807),
  "jsondata"         jsonb

) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  );

INSERT INTO messages (jsondata) VALUES ('{ "user": "user1", "message": "Hello, World"}');
INSERT INTO messages (jsondata) VALUES ('{ "user": "user1", "message": "Hello, How r u"}');
INSERT INTO messages (jsondata) VALUES ('{ "user": "user1", "message": "another message"}');
INSERT INTO messages (jsondata) VALUES ('{ "user": "user1", "message": "sample message"}');


select * from messages;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_message_to_string( d jsonb, out string text )
          AS $func$
            BEGIN
              SELECT INTO string
                string_agg(d->>'message', ' ')
              FROM jsonb_each(d);
              RETURN;
            END;
          $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
          IMMUTABLE;


          CREATE AGGREGATE tsvector_agg (tsvector) (
      SFUNC = tsvector_concat,
      STYPE = tsvector
    );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_message_to_tsvector( d jsonb, out tsv tsvector )
    AS $func$
      BEGIN
        SELECT INTO tsv
          tsvector_agg(to_tsvector(d->>'message'))
          FROM jsonb_each(d);
        RETURN;
      END;
    $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
    IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX ON messages
          USING gin (jsonb_message_to_tsvector(jsondata));
```

I've managed to do this by collecting from other answers. Now, when I query:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_message_to_tsvector(jsondata) @@ 'another'
FROM messages;
```

I get 4 rows with each row has boolean `f`. What am i doing wrong here? How can i search messages inside a `jsonb` column.

```
?column?
f
f
f
f
```

The examples I found on the net shows array of elements. My column is object-only. Does not contains an array. I'm using PostgreSQL 11.

**See demo**: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=411fc432663f3ce16afb9ca62a69c5f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't really make sense as it aggregates the messages from **all** rows. And then you create a FTS vector on all of them. Even if you find a match, you wouldn't know to which column it belongs.

You are also over complicating things with that aggregate. You only need an immutable function to create the tsvector for one row, not for all of them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_message_to_tsvector(d jsonb)
  returns tsvector
AS $func$
  select to_tsvector(d->>'message');
$func$ 
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

Then you can create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON messages
  USING gin (jsonb_message_to_tsvector(jsondata));
```

And the `@@` operator needs a `tsquery` on the right hand side, not a string value:

```
SELECT jsondata, jsonb_message_to_tsvector(jsondata) @@ to_tsquery('another') as is_contained
FROM messages;
```

returns:

```
jsondata                                        | is_contained
------------------------------------------------+-------------
{"user": "user1", "message": "Hello, World"}    | false       
{"user": "user1", "message": "Hello, How r u"}  | false       
{"user": "user1", "message": "another message"} | true        
{"user": "user1", "message": "sample message"}  | false
```

DbFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=507bc5b88a9d8f4b5f0d978d664a4796

---

If you know that the only language is English, you don't even need the immutable function, you can create a tsvector directly from the json column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON messages
  USING gin (to_tsvector('english', jsondata ->> 'message'));

SELECT to_tsvector('english', jsondata ->> 'message') @@ to_tsquery('another') as is_contained
FROM messages;
```

DbFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=30a182a5b97cd24ebf45861440ff7c5b

---

If you only want to see the matches, move the condition to the where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
where to_tsvector('english', jsondata ->> 'message') @@ to_tsquery('another')
```

Comment: But this returns all rows no matter what. How can i only return matched rows? Instead of marking them as `true`.

Comment: @Pratha: use a `where` clause - this is only a copy of your own query (which did not have a where clause)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `jsonb_each_text()`(**or** `jsonb_each()`) function :

```
select (js).key as items, (js).value as strings
  from
  (
   select jsonb_each_text(jsondata) as js
     from messages
  ) q 
 where (js).key = 'message';
```

**or** in this way :

```
select key, v.j->key as strings
  from messages v(id, j) cross join lateral
       jsonb_each_text(v.j) as key
 where key = 'message';
```

**or** `jsonb_object_keys()` function :

```
select key, v.j->key as strings
  from messages v(id, j) cross join lateral
       jsonb_object_keys(v.j) as key
 where key = 'message';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=00a0cbcdc35f6ce80d7051aaeecd5244)</kbd>

Comment: But how do you search specific word or partial words like `another`, `hello` or `anot`, `hell` in message field in jsonb?

Comment: `and (js).value ~* 'hell'` worked for first sample. And if I have millions of messages, how can i index them to work with your sample so that i can search fast?

Comment: @Pratha Consider `where (js).value like '%Hello%'` for the first query as an example like a classical select statement, but I haven't thought about performance I don't know.